# Inherit parent's height without height specified

Tags: html, css

I have the following: [**http://jsfiddle.net/DTyGn/1/**](http://jsfiddle.net/DTyGn/1/)

The problem is that the blue line running down the middle of the divs should only be the height of the parent (`.box`), but that's not possible because there is no specified height for `.box` because the heights can vary.

How can I fix this?

HTML:

```
<div class="box">
    Sample text.
</div>
<div class="box">
    Some more text.<br />
    Different height.
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.box {
    padding: 50px 0;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.box:after {
    content: "";
    height: 100%;
    width: 5px;
    background: blue;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -2.5px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `position:relative` to you .box div. Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/DTyGn/6/

Comment: I feel like an idiot for missing such a simple solution. Thanks. :P

Answer (score 0):

Add an .inner div to both boxes and position:relative to .box and you should be set.

http://jsfiddle.net/DTyGn/5/

**CSS**

```
.box {
    padding: 50px 0;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    position:relative;
}

.inner:after {
    content: "";
    height: 100%;
    width: 5px;
    background: blue;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -2.5px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="box">
  <div class="inner">
    Sample text.
  </div>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <div class="inner">
    Some more text.<br />
    Different height.
  </div>
</div>
```